# No internet access to load balancer aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

guys.
I'm new and trying to create infrastructure of blue-green deployment of aws by terraform.
I've created 2 instances  at 2 public zones, 1 internet gateway, 1 elastic load balancer, security group, 1 vpc.
But I can't login at load balancer dns. I beleive, I fortgot something. Also please advice, if I should create a NAT for public zones, I guess - no.

Main

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region = var.region_name
}


resource "aws_vpc" "main_subnet" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
  tags = {
    Name = "Main Subnet"
  }
}


resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet_1" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main_subnet.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.10.0/24"
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.my-zones.names[0]

  tags = {
    Name = "Public Subnet1"
  }
}


resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet_2" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main_subnet.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.20.0/24"
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.my-zones.names[1]

  tags = {
    Name = "Public Subnet 2"
  }
}


resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnet_1" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main_subnet.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.11.0/24"
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.my-zones.names[0]


  tags = {
    Name = "Private Subnet 1"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnet_2" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main_subnet.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.21.0/24"
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.my-zones.names[1]

  tags = {
    Name = "Private Subnet 2"
  }
}
```

Internet gateway

```
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main_subnet.id

  tags = {
    Name = "Main internet gateway"
  }
}
```

EC2

```
resource "aws_instance" "test_server" {
  ami = "ami-0453cb7b5f2b7fca2"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  user_data = file("init_script.sh")
//  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.my_sg.id]
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.public_subnet_1.id
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.my_sg.id]

  tags = {
    Name = "ExampleAppServerInstance"
  }

  key_name = var.keypair
}



resource "aws_instance" "test_server2" {
  ami = "ami-0453cb7b5f2b7fca2"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  user_data = file("init_script.sh")
  //  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.my_sg.id]
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.public_subnet_2.id
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.my_sg.id]

  tags = {
    Name = "ExampleAppServerInstance2"
  }

  key_name = var.keypair
}
```

Loadbalancer

```
resource "aws_eip" "lb" {
  instance = aws_instance.test_server.id
}

resource "aws_lb" "my_lb" {
  name = "my-lb"
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups = [
    aws_security_group.my_sg.id]
  subnets = [
    aws_subnet.public_subnet_1.id,
    aws_subnet.public_subnet_2.id]

  //  access_logs {
  //    bucket  = aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket.bucket
  //    prefix  = "test-lb-log-"
  //    enabled = true
  //  }

  tags = {
    Name = "My loadbalancer"
  }
}


resource "aws_lb_listener" "front_end" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.my_lb.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.my_tg.arn
  }
}


resource "aws_lb_target_group" "my_tg" {
  name = "http-tg"
  port = 80
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main_subnet.id
  target_type = "instance"
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "host1" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.my_tg.arn
  target_id        = aws_instance.test_server.id
  port             = 80
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "host2" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.my_tg.arn
  target_id        = aws_instance.test_server2.id
  port             = 80
}
```

routing

```
resource "aws_route_table" "web" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main_subnet.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "Net rules"
  }
}
```

SecurityGroup

```
resource "aws_security_group" "my_sg" {
  name = "my_sg"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main_subnet.id

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = var.sg_ports
    content {
      from_port = ingress.value
      to_port = ingress.value
      protocol = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks = [
        "0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
  }

  egress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port = 0
    protocol = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = [
      "0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "allow_http_https_ssh"
  }
}
```

data

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "my-zones"{
  state = "available"
}
```

variables

```
variable "region_name" {
  description = "The desired region of work"
  default = "eu-central-1"
}

variable "sg_ports" {
  type = list(number)
  default = [22, 80, 443]
}


variable "keypair" {
  default = "aws_privatekey"
}
```

init_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
amazon-linux-extras install -y lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2 php7.2
yum install -y httpd mariadb-server
systemctl start httpd
systemctl enable httpd
usermod -a -G apache ec2-user
chown -R ec2-user:apache /var/www
chmod 2775 /var/www
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} \;
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} \;
echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > /var/www/html/index.php
```

Comment: I think you need to associate your `resource "aws_route_table" "web"` route table to public subnet.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was, that I didn't associate the route with public subnets

```
resource "aws_route_table_association" "a" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.public_subnet_1.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.web.id
}


resource "aws_route_table_association" "b" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.public_subnet_2.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.web.id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create NAT gateway for public subnets, NAT are for private subnets which don't have direct Internet Access.

Can you let me know are you trying to SSH your load Balancer DNS, or EC2 instance, also is that Public Subnet EC2 instance or Private one.

Comment: I'm trying to ssh to EC2, also tryed to open webpage at load balancer dns and EC2's ip. EC2 are at public subnets, before creating loadbalancer, all was working good.